# Python Модуль Multiprocessing Не Работает

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Я изучал модуль multiprocessing в питоне. На сайте был приведён пример:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process


def doubler(number):
    """
    Функция умножитель на два
    """
    result = number * 2
    proc = os.getpid()
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by process id: {2}'.format(
        number, result, proc))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
    procs = []

    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        proc = Process(target=doubler, args=(number,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Я запускаю этот код через IDLE но даже ошибки не возникает, просто ничего не происходит. Если это как-то поможет, у меня Python 3.7.1 32-bit, Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Запускайте через CMD. Все работает.

Comment: вывода в консоль в данном случае не будет, так как у Вас разные процессы